# Need to understand how Multiple joins - Left Outer, Right outer, Full outer joins work in a single SQL Query

Tags: sql, join

I have four tables - A,B,C,D. Each table has 1 column: `ID`.

Data:

```
Table A = 1,2,3,4
Table B = 1,2,4,5
Table C = 2,3,4,5
Table D = 1,3,5,7
```

I need help in understanding the output of this SQL query:

```
select d.*, c.*, b.*,a.* 
from d 
  left join c on d.id = c.id 
  right join b on b.id = c.id 
  full outer join a on a.id = b.id;
```

I am very clear till the left join, but after that when the subsequent joins are applied, I do not understand how the result changes.

Answer (score 6):

As per @Pieter's answer, we can work systematically through this:

Taking just the first LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT D.ID AS D, c.ID AS C
from d 
    left join c 
        on d.id = c.id
```

All of Ds rows are returned. NULLS are present for failed joins on C:

```
D   C
1   NULL
3   3
5   5
7   NULL
```

Then, adding the right join to B:

```
SELECT D.ID AS D, c.ID AS C, b.ID AS B
from d 
    left join c 
        on d.id = c.id 
    right join b 
        on b.id = c.id
```

All of Bs rows are returned, with both C and D being NULL where the join fails.
Only 5 is common to D, C and B.

```
D       C       B
NULL    NULL    1
NULL    NULL    2
NULL    NULL    4
5       5       5
```

Finally, the `FULL OUTER JOIN` back to A will add missing rows from either side of the `JOIN`.

This means the '3' from A not present in B is added back, with NULLs for the other columns

```
D       C       B    A
NULL    NULL    1    1
NULL    NULL    2    2
NULL    NULL    4    4
5       5       5    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL 3
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart for your response. Thanks Pieter for the detailed explanation along with the result. It clarified my doubts.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine it as a SQL *stack machine*. Push tables onto the stack as they are encountered, left-to-right, in the FROM clause and perform the join on the two top-most tables as ON clauses are encountered. The result of each join is pushed onto the stack also as it is generated.